# Installing Kotlin Android project fails with INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Attempting to run a Kotlin Android project using Android Studio compiles successfully and generates an APK, but when Studio tries to install the APK on the device the installation fails with `INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT`. Looking through logcat I can see messages similar to:

```
12-13 22:43:57.219: ERROR/dalvikvm(1623): Out-of-order method_idx: 0x2bff then 0x2bff
12-13 22:43:57.219: ERROR/dalvikvm(1623): Trouble with item 897 @ offset 0x13e498
12-13 22:43:57.219: ERROR/dalvikvm(1623): Swap of section type 2006 failed
12-13 22:43:57.219: ERROR/dalvikvm(1623): ERROR: Byte swap + verify failed
12-13 22:43:57.230: ERROR/dalvikvm(1623): Optimization failed
```

The project was converted from Java using the Kotlin IDEA plugin's automatic conversion. There are no compiler warnings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This occurs when a method name collides with a Kotlin-generated etter, for example:

```
class Foo(val bar: Any) {
  fun getBar(): Any {}
}
```

Rename `bar` or `getBar` to something else. For more information see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-3170

Answer (score 0):

Recently the similar issue has been discovered on devices running api 17- with Kotlin `1.0.0-beta-1038`.

To fix this issue use new beta build `1.0.0-beta-1103`.

https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5561799#5561799

Comment: It's not public yet. Should be available next week https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5561782#5561782